# php direct variable assignment

Tags: php, arrays, variables

I'm having a hard time to figure out how to directly assing a value to a array key. I think the code I now use (which works) is inefficient and this code runs a couple thousand times on each import I do.

So I do a foreach loop through an array and one of the actions is to change a array key from `FEMALE` to F or if it's `MALE` to M.

At the moment I pas the value through a string because because the code I tried to set it directly fails.

```
if ($csv[$k] ['gender'] == 'FEMALE') {
  $string = 'F';
} else {
  $string = 'M';
};
$csv[$k] ['gender'] = $string;
```

/edit

The total code of the array function which is ment to load a CSV file and then alter column names and do some improvements on the data (captical's etc) is below.

```
foreach ( $csv as $k=>$v )
{
  $csv[$k] ['firstname']                = ucfirst(strtolower($csv[$k] ['firstname']));
  $csv[$k] ['lastname']                 = ucfirst(strtolower($csv[$k] ['lastname']));
  $csv[$k] ['city']                     = ucfirst(strtolower($csv[$k] ['city']));
  $csv[$k] ['street']                   = ucfirst(strtolower($csv[$k] ['street']));
  $csv[$k] ['email']                    = strtolower($csv[$k] ['email']);

  if ($csv[$k] ['gender'] == 'FEMALE') {
    $string = 'F';
  } else {
    $string = 'M';
  };
  $csv[$k] ['gender'] = $string;
}
```

Comment: can you paste the code a few lines before this code segment?

Comment: How are you using the string after is it being saved again or is it only used in the loop? Rather than setting a variable you could just do a $csv[$k]['gender'][0] to always get the first character

Comment: I'm new to stackoverflow, so also figuring out how to correctly edit things.

Comment: You can always get stuff like this “shorter” by using the ternary operator, `$csv[$k]['gender'] = $csv[$k]['gender'] == 'FEMALE' ? 'F' : 'M';` What _reads_ better is for you to decide … after all, you still need to understand what the code does when you look at it tomorrow, next month, one year from now …

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to simplify your code snippet somewhat you could use this:

```
$csv[$k]['gender']  = ( $csv[$k]['gender'] == "FEMALE" ) ? "F" : "M";
```

This will set $csv[$k]['gender'] to "F" if "female" is true, or "M" if false.

Also, if all you want is to set the value from Male/Female to F/M you could just substring it

```
$csv[$k]['gender'] = substring( $csv[$k]['gender'], 0, 1 );
```

Comment: I think that's it. But also many thanks to the (very fast) other commentors. I used the first example as I think I will re-use the code elsewhere where CSV files could have other names (languages) to indicate male/female.